# How to insert specified number of Minor ticks between major ticks axis in a Chart in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I need to draw specific number of minor ticks between two ticks of vertical axis of column chart based on user input.

Eg:if user is providing 2 as 'number of minor ticks' there should be two minor ticks between two ticks of axis.How can this be done in Flex Cartesian Chart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shall use `LinearAxis` as your axis in that case.

`LinearAxis` conatins `interval` and `minorInterval` properties.
If you want to see **N** minor ticks between major ticks, then do

```
axis.minorInterval = axis.interval / (N+1)
```

Be careful: minor ticks are always drawn, so you shall choose good stroke and placement for them if you want them to be not visible on major ticks.

Here is example chart with 3 minor ticks between major ticks(sorry, made a horizontal axis...but I guess it does not matter a lot for you):

```
                   >
<fx:Declarations>       

</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

        [Bindable]
        public var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{x:10, y:2},
            {x:1, y:2},
            {x:2, y:2},
            {x:3, y:3},
            {x:4, y:2},
            {x:5, y:2},
            {x:6, y:2}
            ]
        );
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:LineChart dataProvider="{arr}" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis 
            id="a"
            interval="4" 
            minorInterval="1"
            maximumLabelPrecision="4"                       
            />
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer id="ax" axis="{a}" minorTickLength="5" tickLength="10"
                         minorTickPlacement="outside"                            
                         tickPlacement="outside"                             
                         >
            <mx:minorTickStroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke />
            </mx:minorTickStroke>   
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries yField="y" xField="x" >              
        </mx:LineSeries>
    </mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
```